# How to communicate processes of a tree without external mechanisms

Tags: c, process, tree

I need to build a process tree in C using fork() with the following shape:

[image: Process tree]

I have to send signals between them so I would also like to know if there is any way to store the PIDs of the processes in an array or something else, so each process has the PIDs of the others. The issue is I have some restrictions like not using pipes, files, or other external mechanisms to share data between processes. Sleep and exec can't be used neither.

This is how I have to send signals between them:

[image: Signal directions]

Comment: shared memory isn't enough?

Comment: You just need to do the `fork()`s in the right order, calling `getpid()` or `getppid()` occasionally.

Comment: ... in particular, it is not necessary for each process to have the PIDs of *all* the others.  Each one just needs the PIDs of the the ones it needs to signal.  The exercise appears designed to afford a solution along the lines that @EOF suggests.

Comment: So I just have to create them in a certain order so at the moment they are created, the PID of the process they will send a signal is already created? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> So I just have to create them in a certain order so at the moment they are created, the PID of the process they will send a signal is already created?

Right - in particular H4 has to be forked before H3/N3, so that H4 is known to N3. Demo:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *si, void *u)
{
    printf("%d received signal from %d %s\n", getpid(), si->si_pid,
                                                        si->si_value.sival_ptr);
}

main()
{
    // for demo, defer signal delivery until process unmasks the signal
    sigset_t set, oldset;
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGRTMIN);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &oldset);

    sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &(struct sigaction){ .sa_sigaction = handler,
                                             .sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO }, NULL);
    pid_t P = getpid();
    pid_t H1 = fork();          if (H1 < 0) perror("H1"), exit(1);
    if (H1 == 0)
    {
        // use sigqueue() instead of kill(), so can pass sender ID
        sigqueue(P, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "H1"});
        sigsuspend(&oldset);
        exit(0);
    }
    pid_t H2 = fork();          if (H2 < 0) perror("H2"), exit(1);
    if (H2 == 0)
    {
        pid_t N2 = fork();      if (N2 < 0) perror("N2"), exit(1);
        if (N2 == 0)
        {
            sigqueue(H1, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "N2"});
            sigsuspend(&oldset);
            exit(0);
        }
        sigqueue(N2, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "H2"});
        sigsuspend(&oldset);
        exit(0);
    }
    sigqueue(H2, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "P"});
    pid_t H4 = fork();          if (H4 < 0) perror("H4"), exit(1);
    if (H4 == 0)
    {
        sigqueue(P, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "H4"});
        sigsuspend(&oldset);
        exit(0);
    }
    pid_t H3 = fork();          if (H3 < 0) perror("H3"), exit(1);
    if (H3 == 0)
    {
        pid_t N3 = fork();      if (N3 < 0) perror("N3"), exit(1);
        if (N3 == 0)
        {
            sigqueue(H4, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "N3"});
            sigsuspend(&oldset);
            exit(0);
        }
        sigqueue(N3, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "H3"});
        sigsuspend(&oldset);
        exit(0);
    }
    sigqueue(H3, SIGRTMIN, (union sigval){.sival_ptr = "P"});
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, NULL);
    do ; while (wait(NULL) > 0 || errno != ECHILD);
}
```

Example output:

```
1074 received signal from 1072 P
1072 received signal from 1073 H1
1072 received signal from 1076 H4
1075 received signal from 1074 H2
1073 received signal from 1075 N2
1077 received signal from 1072 P
1076 received signal from 1078 N3
1078 received signal from 1077 H3
```